# Could not create the view: ...JavadocHover$PresenterControlCreator: method <init>()V not found

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting the below exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.
    JavadocHover$PresenterControlCreator: method <init>()V not found.
```

I am getting this when i am trying to view blueprint file specific to my application. but for the above exception, i tried to get the org.eclipse.jdt jar from the internet and placed in both plugins and features. but the exception is not yet solved. i have spent hours in figuring it out. but no luck... 
Experts, the correct plugin should solve this issue right? i am using eclipse indigo . Please let me know your thoughts. looking forward for your advice. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting 3.6 JavadocHover$PresenterControlCreator does not have a no parameter constructor. Try using the jdt plugins from Eclipse 3.5.

Comment: thanks. i tried eclipse Galileo and it worked for me. Thanks!